# How to make Reduce give this relation about the power of product property?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am brushing up on my school math.

Given $(a b)^n$ then exponent can be distributed resulting in $a^n  b^n$ under the following conditions.

1. if $n$ is integer and $a,b$ are both real numbers (regardless of sign).
2. if $n$ is instead a rational number $\frac{r}{s}$, and $a,b$ are reals, then now $a,b$ must be both positive or one is positive and the second is negative, but not both negative.

I am only interested in the case when exponent is integer or rational.

How to use Reduce to show/verify these two rules above?  Or is there a better command to use?

```
Reduce[(a*b)^n==a^n*b^n]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Reduce[(a*b)^(1/3)==a^(1/3)*b^(1/3)&&Element[{a,b},Reals]]
```

seems to hang.

i.e. I wanted Reduce to show me these rules, but all my attempts failed. Here is one example of the second rule above showing why both $a,b$ can't be negative. But all other cases are allowed.

```
(3*4)^(2/3)//N
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
(-3)^(2/3)*(-4)^(2/3)//N
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: How about `PowerExpand[(a*b)^n, 
 Assumptions -> 
  a != 0 && b != 0 && a \[Element] Complexes && 
   b \[Element] Complexes && n \[Element] Integers]` which results in `a^n b^n`?  The condition `a != 0 && b != 0` stands to avoid division by zero.

Comment: How about `Simplify[(a b)^n - a^n b^n, Element[n, Integers]]` which results in `0`? It should be noticed that Mathematica's math is not traditional here.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`PowerExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PowerExpand) with the option [`Assumptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assumptions)->[`True`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/True) to find out when the expansion is permitted:

```
PowerExpand[(a b)^n, Assumptions->True]
```

> a^n b^n E^(2 I n π Floor[1/2 - Arg[a]/(2 π) - Arg[b]/(2 π)])

Look at the [`Floor`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Floor) part of the exponential. This can be -1, 0, or 1 only, since the [`Arg`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Arg) is restricted to (-π, π]. If the floor is 0, than the expansion is true. If the floor is -1 or 1, then the expansion is only true when `n` is an integer.

Comment: I'd like to notice that division by zero is allowed in the above since `Arg[0]` results in `0`. We see Mathematica's math differs from traditional math.